# Saltstack - Unable to print output in Jinja templating

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I am trying to reuse the output of a command in Saltstack, but when I try to print the output using "cmd.run", it is failing with the below error. Not sure in which format the data is getting returned from "cmd.run".

```
{% set output = salt['cmd.shell']('ifconfig') %}

display:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo '{{ output }}'
```

**Error:**

```
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    Rendering SLS 'base:patching.install_patches' failed: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be due to the placement of quotes. The single quotes are required around the entire command to run.

Below should work:

```
{% set output = salt['cmd.shell']('ifconfig') %}

display:
  cmd.run:
    - name: 'echo "{{ output }}"'
```

Comment: Because the output probably contained `:`, which the YAML parser tried to interpret

Comment: That's very likely, and the `ifconfig` output is typically very verbose with multiple lines as well.

Comment: `{{ output | yaml_encode }}` would be the better solution, in case it contains quotes as well